# On Deployment file path substitution Java

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, path

I have an application with several paths and filenames to use
All of them are relative, not absolute. When I was building a regular Java app, it was fine, but now I turned it into Tomcat web app

```
timetables
timteables.db
.exclude
.master
```

I need to substitute something like `/usr/share/<APPNAME>` and `/var/<APPNAME>`, when I deploy my app into tomcat. I use `listener-class` in my `web.xml`. How can I correctly add them? What is the Java way to solve this? I don't want to hard-code them for several reasons: because it's not beautiful and correct, and, as my project is open-source, I don't want to reveal my own paths.

Comment: Sorry, where are these files? Presumably not _in_ the war? If not, why not? Security concerns or are they system files?

Comment: @BoristheSpider while testing they are in project directory, but for security concerns, I wan't to move them out of /webapp directory at all

Comment: Okay, security concerns. Well, it should be noted that on any decent Tomcat deployment the Tomcat user would not be allowed to even read files outside of it's base and home - this is for security. It should also be noted that placing files in WEB-INF is perfectly secure (otherwise users would be able to access web.xml) and this is usually the accepted method. If you want to access files outside of tomcat's location you would need to guarantee that that location is readable by tomcat. You could configure the path with init parameters.

Comment: @BoristheSpider and if I need static context, I can place them in my source directory in WEB-INF, then compile and make .war package and deploy? Is it ok?

Comment: Exactly. Then the files are in your classpath and you can easily get them with the classloader.